# How to get Apposite action of remove_menu_page();

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a customoize menu link in wordpress admin menubar .i want exactly opposite action of   `remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );`  .As `remove_menu_page()` removes required link from menubar .  i want to add required menu to admin menubar . is it possible through function.php

Comment: [add_menu_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page). Yes, really.

Comment: ok, add_menu_page. i have used in plugin page . will it be working in function.php too ?

Comment: Yes. Use it inside the admin_menu action.

Comment: ok thanks ,@ vard i am trying to use it in function.php

Answer (score 1):

To add a new menu page to the admin pages create a function using `add_menu_page()`, like so:

```
function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'manage_options', 'custompage', 'my_custom_menu_page', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 ); 
}
```

Then register that function like so:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
```

Last, but not least, you have to create a second function holding whatever settings you want to add to your new settings page. In the above function this function is set to my_custom_menu_page(). Name it whatever you like.

```
function my_custom_menu_page(){
    echo "Admin Page Test"; 
}
```

You can read more, and find this exact [example in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page). Also you should read up on the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

A superb introduction to the Settings API was written by Otto, and [you'll find it here](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/). It's well worth your time, and if you read it carefully you should be all set to create your custom settings in (close to) no time.